# Consulta mysql html

Tags: html, mysql

Tengo una consulta que es esta

```
SELECT COUNT(id_orden) as cuantas FROM `orden_trabajo` ORDER BY status
```

esta me arroja un resultado de

```
cuantas
46
```

mi problema es que no puedo pasar este resultado de la consulta a un html.
mi idea fue pasarlo a una funcion de esta forma

```
function total(){
include("dbconnect.php");
$total=0;
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS
cuantas FROM orden_trabajo ORDER BY status ");
$sql->execute();
if ($sql->rowCount () > 0){
while($total=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
return $total['no_reporte']; 
  }
 }else{
return "NA";
 }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no puedes?¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: no me manda nada de resultado al html, de esta forma lo mando llamar  `<?php echo .total($total['no_reporte']).; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Asumimos que la conexión a tu base da datos es correcta y que el archivo `dbconnect.php` funciona bien.

En esta parte:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT orden_trabajo.status, COUNT(id_orden) AS
```

cuantas FROM orden_trabajo ORDER BY status ");

seleccionas `orden_trabajo.status` y `COUNT(id_orden)`(lo renombras
`cuantas`) y después retornas `no_reporte`:

```
return $total['no_reporte'];
```

esa variable(`no_reporte`) no existe. Por eso no retorna nada. Modificala por

```
return $total['cuantas'];
```

Comment: muchas gracias, tenias razon en la parte de la variable, al final quedo de la siguiente manera 
      `echo "<strong>El numero total de Ordenes:</strong>";`   `echo $rows['cuantas'];`

Comment: exactamente, si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada